# How to prove this following infinite sine sums?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a little problem to prove the following trigonometric identities:

Prove that:

$$ \frac{1}{\sin A\sin 2A} +\frac{1}{\sin 2A\sin 3A} +\frac{1}{\sin 3A\sin 4A}+\ldots= \frac{\cot A-\cot(n+1)A}{\sin A} $$

I have already tried it and only get the cosecant form only, not cotangent form.
Please show your steps, so I can understand the solution.
Thanks

Comment: On one side there is an infinite sum and on this other side there is a number $n$ undefined. Moreover, what is $A$ ? Any real or complex number or a specific value ?

Comment: I suppose the sum in the LHS goes up to $\frac1{\sin(nA)\sin((n+1)A)}$ because then it holds for $n=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left formula must be $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{sin(kA)sin((k+1)A)}$$ so, you can use a reccurence on n.

If n=0, both sides are null.

If the equality is true for a rank $n$, you just have to show that $$(*)\frac1{sin((n+1)A)sin((n+2)A)}=\frac{cot((n+2)A)-cot((n+1)A)}{sin(A)}$$

The right hand side give $$\frac{cos((n+2)A)}{sin(A)sin(n+2)A} -\frac{cos((n+1)A}{sin(A)sin((n+1)A)}$$

And you can reduce and obtain : $$\frac{sin((n+1)A)cos((n+2)A)-sin((n+2)A)cos((n+1)A)}{sin(A)sin((n+1)A)sin((n+2)A)}$$

The numerator is equal to $\sin(A)$ beacause of trigonometrical identity. So you have the formula $(*)$ which proves the formula for the next rank.